# How does flipboard fetch Google plus stream in Android?

Tags: android, api, google-plus

As per title: how does flipboard fetch the google plus timeline/stream? I tried with the plus v1 api and PlusClient provided by Google play library but seems like I'm only allowed to fetch my posts, also, there isn't anything useful on github... I can only find samples on how to post content and fetch single users timeline 
Anyone can point me? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flipboard uses a private API they have licensed access to from Google. It sounded like it was going to be [made available to all](http://www.theverge.com/2012/6/19/3096483/flipboard-google-plus-partnership-integration) but it has not.